# Использование прямой и инверсной кинематик с RealSense

Tags: unity3d

Захотелось сделать игрушку, в которой перед *RealSense* пользователь будет махать руками и на экране будет видно, как двигаются его руки.

Попробовал прикрутить прямую кинематику. Получаю данные положения костей рук, обновляю позицию костей в 3D модели. Вытягиваются кисти до заданных позиций, всё остальное на месте.

Чтобы двигались локти, плечи и т.п., решил воспользоваться инверсной кинематикой. Сделал всё по руководствам: тяну руки к точкам, заданным на ладонях.

Всё работает, но при этом перестала работать прямая кинематика: пальцы уже не тянутся, кисть не разворачивается. Такое чувство, что после `OnAnimatorIK` запускается расчет *IK* и прямая кинематика пересчитывается.

В какое место вклиниться, чтобы работало и то, и другое? Возможно ли такое сделать?

Вот код контроллера рук

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HandsController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public HandsViewer handsViewer = null;
    public Animator animator = null;
    private GameObject[][] myJoints;
    private bool isOk = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        isOk = handsViewer != null || ErrorInfo("Не задан HandsViewer");
        isOk = isOk && animator != null || ErrorInfo("Не задан Animator");
    }

    bool ErrorInfo(string mes)
    {
        Debug.LogError(mes, this);
        return false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!isOk) return;

    }

    void OnAnimatorIK()
    {
        if (!isOk) return;
        if (animator)
        {
            if (handsViewer.handIndx.ContainsValue(PXCMHandData.BodySideType.BODY_SIDE_LEFT))
            {
                animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.LeftHand, myJoints[(handsViewer.handIndx[0] == PXCMHandData.BodySideType.BODY_SIDE_LEFT ? 0 : 1)][1].transform.position);
                animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.LeftHand, 1f);
            }
            if (handsViewer.handIndx.ContainsValue(PXCMHandData.BodySideType.BODY_SIDE_RIGHT))
            {
                animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, myJoints[(handsViewer.handIndx[0] == PXCMHandData.BodySideType.BODY_SIDE_RIGHT ? 0 : 1)][1].transform.position);
                animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, 1f);
            }
        }
        myJoints = handsViewer.myJoints; //Array of Joint GameObjects
        for (int i = 0; i < handsViewer.MaxHands; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < handsViewer.MaxJoints; j++)
            {
                if (myJoints[i][j] == null || !myJoints[i][j].activeSelf) continue;
                Transform t = myJoints[i][j].transform;
                Transform t2 = GetJoint(i, j);
                if (t2 != null) t2.position = t.position;
            }
        }
    }

    Transform GetJoint(int handNum, int jointNum)
    {
        HumanBodyBones bone = HumanBodyBones.LastBone;
        Transform t = null;
        if (handsViewer.handIndx.ContainsKey(handNum))
            switch (handsViewer.handIndx[handNum])
            {
                case PXCMHandData.BodySideType.BODY_SIDE_LEFT:
                    switch (jointNum)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.LeftHand;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.LeftThumbProximal;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.LeftThumbIntermediate;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.LeftThumbDistal;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.LeftIndexProximal;
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.LeftIndexIntermediate;
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.LeftIndexDistal;
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.LeftMiddleProximal;
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.LeftMiddleIntermediate;
                            break;
                        case 12:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.LeftMiddleDistal;
                            break;
                        case 14:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.LeftRingProximal;
                            break;
                        case 15:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.LeftRingIntermediate;
                            break;
                        case 16:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.LeftRingDistal;
                            break;
                        case 18:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.LeftLittleProximal;
                            break;
                        case 19:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.LeftLittleIntermediate;
                            break;
                        case 20:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.LeftLittleDistal;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case PXCMHandData.BodySideType.BODY_SIDE_RIGHT:
                    switch (jointNum)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.RightHand;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.RightThumbProximal;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.RightThumbIntermediate;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.RightThumbDistal;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.RightIndexProximal;
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.RightIndexIntermediate;
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.RightIndexDistal;
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.RightMiddleProximal;
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.RightMiddleIntermediate;
                            break;
                        case 12:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.RightMiddleDistal;
                            break;
                        case 14:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.RightRingProximal;
                            break;
                        case 15:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.RightRingIntermediate;
                            break;
                        case 16:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.RightRingDistal;
                            break;
                        case 18:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.RightLittleProximal;
                            break;
                        case 19:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.RightLittleIntermediate;
                            break;
                        case 20:
                            bone = HumanBodyBones.RightLittleDistal;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        if (bone != HumanBodyBones.LastBone)
            t = animator.GetBoneTransform(bone);
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, разбейте блок текста на параграфы.

Comment: @KromStern да ладно параграфы - вероятно, весь этот блок описывает какой-то код, которого при этом в вопросе нет.

Comment: @Regent: я так даже вчитываться не стал, хотя ИК и занимался

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте привязать к пальцам и костям рук по предмету, положение которых задается в пространстве через данные от RealSense, а всё остальное пусть считается через инверсную кинематику. И волки сыты (положение кистей рук вычислено по факту), и овцы целы (все остальные кости тоже в правильном положении).

Comment: Добавил код в первый пост. Как раз как вы советуете так и пытался сделать. Но когда отрабатывает инверсная она переписывает те позиции которые я выставил через прямую кинематику.

Comment: Хмм. Как я понимаю принцип работы инверсной кинематики, есть точки, положение которых задается и не подлежит изменениям в ИК, и есть скелет (суставы и кости), которые имеют всякие там жесткости, углы поворота итд, и вот их положение считает ИК. Нужно, грубо говоря, связать "костью" предмет, не подчиняющийся ИК, и скелет, и двигать предмет. Проверьте, есть ли на предмете флаг "пересчитывать положение при ИК", такой должен существовать.

Comment: Я настроил маску гуманоида. Отключил IK для ног, включил для рук. Попробовал отключить на кистях маску (до этого пробовал и с действующей кистью). Эффект одинаковый. Руки тянутся за целью и выставляются в требуемую позицию, вот только после расчета инверсной кинематики значения для пальцев выставляются в значения определенные через скелет (суставы и кости).  Сделал два слоя, один с IK второй сверху только для рук который должен перекрывать IK. Но вот как конкретно для этого слоя указать что нужно выставлять кости не знаю.